# Validation of data for certain specific special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I want to add validations to my rails application. I have added in my model,

```
validates_format_of :description, :with => /^[a-zA-Z\d ]*$/i,:message =>
 "can only contain letters and numbers."
```

But now I want some specific special characters (like for ex- `:`) to be allowed.

How would I add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them to your regular expression inside the square brackets. To add a colon:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d :]*$/
```

Be careful, though, there are a few special characters that need to be escaped with a backslash: `. | ( ) [ ] { } + \ ^ $ * ?`.  To add a period to your set, use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d \.]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add them into the regex you have:

```
validates_format_of :description, :with => /^[a-zA-Z\d\s:]*$/i,:message =>
 "can only contain letters and numbers."
```

(I changed the literal whitespace character in your regular expression to a `\s` escape as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want all standard word characters (I know you haven't mentioned underscore explicitly) in addition to spaces and colon:

/^[\w\s:]*$/